# What was Spook's real name?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

I was somewhat surprised on rereading through the first *Mistborn* trilogy to find, in reference to Spook's given name of Lestibournes:

> Lestibournes.  Lefting I'm born.
>
> Street slang for "I've been abandoned."

I hadn't remembered this at all (despite remembering the scene it's in), so I'm not sure what else I missed.  I know Lestibournes is the name he gave Clubs when Clubs "bought" and rescued him from the plantation and took him to Luthadel.  I know Spook is the name Kelsier gave him, ostensibly because he found Lestibournes too hard to say (or maybe because Kelsier knew exactly what his chosen name meant), and Spook stuck with that nickname for the most part after that.

Are there any references at all to his original name, the one he left behind?  Failing that, is there any word from the author?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **firstRainbowRose (17 October 2008)**
>
> I have a rather simple question. What was Spook's real name? He gives a easternese slang term that becomes his name, then he goes by his Kelsier-given nick. So, what was his birth name? (Yes, I wonder about random things like that.)
>
> **Brandon Sanderson (20 October 2008)**
>
> Jedal. After his father.
>
> Which is the reason why Spook didn't like using it.
>
> <sub>from https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=727#67</sub>

Comment: Is there a better source for that than a fan forum? Anyone can say anything there, after all—presumably Brandon Sanderson got this piece of information from somewhere to begin with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sadly, I can't find a better source, although he does reveal information that only the author would know, which has since been revealed by the author or published (names of the final metals, fact that hemalurgy isn't dead, a bit about the afterlife etc.) so I feel reasonably confident that this really was Brandon Sanderson

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Theoryland is a bit more than just a fan forum. It's *the* go-to resource for all Word of God information on the Wheel of Time, Mistborn, etc. books. A great collection of interviews. And since Brandon Sanderson is the author, he didn't need to "g[e]t this piece of information from somewhere" :-) +1 to Mithrandir for a nice find!

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have to admit I've never heard of_Mistborn_, so I'd missed that Brandon Sanderson was the author. If I'd looked a bit closer, I would probably have realised that he's the one answering _all_ the questions there, not just another user on a site. Mea culpa!